# Redirection from Paypal showing error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Paypal Pay Now form for the payment in my Laravel 5.2 website. I have setup auto return URL in my business profile website preference settings. While its redirecting to my website URL then showing errors like following-

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
```

I am using get method in my route for the URL-

```
Route::get('site/paymentsuccess', 'SiteController@paymentsuccess');
```

If I use `post` method then its showing me -

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

Looking forward for some expert advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove this url from the verifyToken middleware 
go tho the : app->Http->Middleware->VerifyCsrfToken.php
and then add "/site/paymentsuccess" to the `$except` array

Comment: Thank you! It worked for post request and changing based on your advice.